# Managed Package Field - Cannot resolve custom field in VisualForce Page

Tags: managed-package

I have a custom object inside a managed package on my developer org called:

`EFCAIS__Session__c`

I have a field on this object called Date:

`EFCAIS__Date__c`

When I try to bind it with an apex:inputField in my visualforce page, I get the following error:

`Could not resolve field 'Date__c' from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!newSession.Date__c}' in page EFCAIS:DevelopmentCentreRegister`

Here is the relevant controller code:

`global EFCAIS__Session__c newSession {get;set;} {newSession = new EFCAIS__Session__c(EFCAIS__Date__c = Date.today());}`

Interestingly, the following works fine:

`<apex:inputfield value="{!newSession.Name}" required="true"/>`

However, this is what causes the error:

`<apex:inputfield value="{!newSession.Date__c}" required="true"/>`

[image: These are my fields on the EFCAIS_Session__c object.]

Comment: You have installed the package containing object and its field in your dev org. And you have created the visualforce page in destination Developer org?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I created an unmanaged package in a sandbox, and then installed it into this developer org (where I am trying to create the page) to package it into a managed package.

Comment: This works? `<apex:inputfield value="{!newSession.EFCAIS__Date__c}" required="true"/>`?

Comment: When I add `<apex:inputfield value="{!newSession.EFCAIS__Date__c}" required="true"/>` to my Visualforce page it reverts to `<apex:inputfield value="{!newSession.Date__c}" required="true"/>`. Do you believe this is a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two scenarios:

1. If the visualforce page and controller is part of package:

   - Namespace prefix must not be referred in any place except where you want to access object/field dynamically.
   - Replace `EFCAIS__Session__c` with `Session__c` in your apex code.
   - From documentation: [Namespace Prefix](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_namespace_prefix.htm)-

     > Only use namespace prefixes when referring to custom objects and fields in managed packages that have been installed to your organization from the AppExchange.
2. If page and class are not part of package:

   - Code is created in destination org after package is being installed, you would need to add a package prefix while accessing object and field API names.
   - In your example, it works Name because its a standard field. For custom field part of package, you would need to use the prefix as below:

     ```
     <apex:inputfield value="{!newSession.EFCAIS__Date__c}" required="true"/>
     ```

Comment: Hi Rahul, I have changed it to `public Session__c newSession {get;set;} {newSession = new Session__c(Date__c = Date.today());} ` and I'm still receiving the error for some reason.